# how do i group customer entries using months across different years in ssrs reports in nav

Tags: reporting-services, nav

I am trying to get Sum of each customer ledger entries and group the Ssrs report into months across different years. For instance, I should be able to filter with the year 011117..310318, this should give me entries of each customer grouped per month: November, December, Jan(18), Feb,  Match.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a matrix in your report.

Add the matrix and set the row group to group by Customer (whatever makes the customer unique such as an ID).

Add column groups by month and then a parent column group by year. If you don't have separate columns for months and years in your dataset, you can use expression into the group expression such as..

```
=Month(Fields!myDateField.Value)
=Year(Fields!myDateField.Value)
```

In the data 'cell' just drag the value you want to aggregate there.

That should give you a basic working matrix.

If you need more help refer to the SSRS documentation on the matrix control.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/create-a-matrix-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15